# Custom tool warning : unable to load one of the requested types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cloud

I get a warning trying to add a *Cloud Service Reference* from another project running and to use it on a windows phone 7 project to communicate with.

I get a warning:

> Custom tool warning: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

This warning comes from the file `Reference.svcmap`

I tried to reload the Service Reference as I found on some other website but still doesn't work and I'm getting that warning again.

Thanks

Comment: What are your configuration options? Right-click service reference, select 'Configure Service Reference'.

Comment: Client Address refers to the cloud service.
Collection type: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection
Dictionary Collection type: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
Reuse types in referenced assemblies : and reuse types in all referenced assemblies

Comment: I have an idea, but can you try this first: remove the reference, save and shut down VS - restart once the `devenv` process is dead and try re-adding the reference then build. Any good?

Comment: Furthermore, can you show us your `DataContract`'s?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I tried to remove the reference and re-add. Not working

Comment: Ah, but did you shut down VS in between doing so?

Comment: You see, it may have something to do with the specified collection types, but would like to rule this mentioned possibility out initially.

Comment: I shut down VS too but doesn't work. I don't think that collection types causing problem

Comment: I've been planning on attempting to reproduce your issue in order to supply a fix, apologies for the severe delay, please bear with me and I'll get to it ASAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get rid of warnings like this by adding a Web Service, not as a Service Reference, but as a Web Reference.

Steps on how to do this:

1. Right-click on the project and choose *Add Service Reference*.
2. In the Add Service reference dialog, press the *Advanced* button.
3. In the Service Reference Settings dialog, press the *Add Web Reference*.
4. In the Add Web Reference dialog, the URL of the Web Service can be specified.

Comment: where do you find this Add Web Reference button? All I get in Service ReferenceSettings is client and data type...

Comment: When having the dialog with the title "Service Reference Settings" opened, the _Add Web Reference_ button should be at the bottom of the dialog, just below the Compatibility section label, and just above the dialog's _OK_ and _Cancel_ buttons.

Comment: Just noticed that it may not be available if you are trying to configure a Service Reference that already exist. For this to work, make sure you start at step one: _Add Service Reference_.